# tkinter: input entry & generate result without button press

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first attempt at tkinter. I was using this [tutorial](https://datatofish.com/entry-box-tkinter/), code below, where a user input a number, and with a button generate a result at another window.

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def getSquareRoot ():  
    x1 = entry1.get()
    
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= float(x1)**0.5)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Get the Square Root', command=getSquareRoot)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I do this directly, without the button? I.e., Enter number > result is generated immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `bind` for this effect, when you press a binded key, the function gets called and executed.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack(pady=(20, 0), padx=10)
label1 = tk.Label(root)


def getSquareRoot(event=None):
    root.after(1000,getSquareRoot)
    x1 = entry1.get()
    try:
        sqrt = float(x1)**0.5
    except:
        sqrt = ''
    label1.config(text=sqrt)
    label1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(text='Get the Square Root', command=getSquareRoot)
button1.pack(pady=(0, 20))

entry1.bind('<Return>', getSquareRoot)
root.after(5000,getSquareRoot)
root.mainloop()
```

If you press the Enter key at the entry widget, it will generate the output for you, without hitting any buttons.

Comment: very sorry, I just realised that my post was v misleading... my interpretation of "window" actually means `canvas1.create_window()` function, just edited the question

Comment: @Jake I dont think its the accurate way to use canvas here, as it will lead to overwriting of labels. Do you want to continue using it though?

Comment: i think its fine, my aim is to minimise the number of clicks & keystrokes to generate the result (something like in Excel using formulas, where I just need to change a cell, and the related cells will be updated accordingly)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Do u know if its possible to generate the results even without pressing Enter?

Comment: @Jake Its possible, but the how will python know that the entry is complete, for example if the person wants to enter '25' but while entering something like 2, python would take that number up and find the square root of it

Comment: oh, if it can regenerate the new result after I add the latter number 5, that will be fine~

Comment: Ive updated my answer, such that the code checks if there is an input every 5 second, so you dont need an press enter

Comment: It works as desired :) thanks!~ can just ask why the need to put the root.after() within the function and outside for it to work?

Comment: basically outside the function triggers it once only, inside the function would keep on triggering it whenever the function is called, so its like a loop, its keeps on calling itself. Im a beginner so i just did with what came to my mind first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `Entry` widget contents without using the keyboard then use a mouse key press.

```py
entry1.bind('<Double-Button-1>', getSquareRoot)
```

or

```py
entry1.bind('<Button-3>', getSquareRoot)
```